# Can a single server serve 2 different websites?

Tags: networking, web, ip-address, ports

If a single server can serve 2 different sites ..how does the server knows which site to transfer the request it received on port 80?

Comment: Only one 'application' can listen to a port. However, this itself may dispatch to the underlying HTTP subsytem. This is how [HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.1) works: note "port sharing". IIS can run many sites - differentiated by hostname and/or path - from a single 'server'. It is also possible to perform port/route translations at a network layer, such that internally there are distinct applications listening to different ports (HTTPS requires edge-decryption for this method if the path is used).

Comment: Heck, even something like an standard Apache config allows 'routing' of different URLs and/or hosts to different modules/handlers. These handlers could be for 'different sites'.

Comment: lot of applications might be running on the server side how to does the server knows which application to run at port 80.for ex if user makes a http request to 2 applications which are on the same server..then to which application will port 80 get alloted?

Comment: **Only one 'application' can listen to a port..** Then keep reading from there.

Answer (score 1):

An web server generally looks at the host name present in the HTTP request headers. It can serve virtually unlimited *vhosts*.